# How to install Spark 2.6.3?

Tags: software-installation

I tried downloading the zip file but I couldn't find any binary or install file.

Is it available via apt or can we access the latest .deb file somehow?

### edit

uname -a

> Linux XXXX 2.6.38-11-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 12 21:17:25 UTC
>   2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: It would help to know on which Ubuntu version you are trying to install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [.tar.gz file](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=spark/spark_2_6_3.tar.gz) (not .zip) downloaded from their website (you did try downloading Linux version, didn't you?) contains a file called `starter` which is a shell script.

I have a strong suspicion this file can be used to start Spark 2.6.3

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Its working, when I ran Spark Shell Script.

Comment: @user7044 if the answer solves your problem you can mark it as a solution :)